# how to solve this firebase IllegalStateException when use goolge analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

Projects

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Module

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.0'
}
```

It just happened in 8.0 system, but i haven't used any firebase code in my project

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{e2ab7c6 u0a30 CEM  idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
           at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1538)
           at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1484)
           at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:663)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzbi(Unknown Source:149)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzbi(Unknown Source:235)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzt(Unknown Source:20)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzbi(Unknown Source)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzGu(Unknown Source:57)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.getCreationTime(Unknown Source:49)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source:3)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzaae(Unknown Source:4)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzH(Unknown Source:37)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source:35)
           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I can't remove firebase from my project, is there other ways to solve this problem?

[Fabric report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dsmx.png)

Comment: add the code where is cause the issue

Comment: fabric crashlytics shows it caused by android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1538)

Comment: i don't know where cause the issue

Comment: share the fabric report

Comment: were you able to fix this issue. I also encountered the issue in my application.
@OmInfowaveDevelopers, this error is only being reported in Google play console  and not in fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You should first try on the main menu, choose **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**. this can happen if Android studio gets in a bad state. 
It should also be noted that firebase is probably in play-services-analytics. Ever since google bought them out they have put firebase in many of their google play services libraries.